# How can I get my system to use DVI on boot (BIOS) when it now uses VGA on my dual monitor setup?

Tags: dvi, vga

I am scaling down to just one monitor due to space constraints (boo!) so I want to get rid of my smaller VGA connected screen but the problem is that the BIOS and GRUB display on the VGA screen.  If I just disconnect the VGA I can't get anything on the DVI screen.

I've looked through the BIOS and can't find anything that seems correct but I am probably missing something obvious.

I have an NVIDIA card and I dual boot windows and ubuntu.

How can I redirect all the video output to the DVI?

Comment: There should be a BIOS setting for which display is primary. If all else fails, disable the onboard video.

Comment: I guess in this case it couldn't hurt to be more specific about the card. :)

Comment: NVIDIA GeForce 8500GT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved itself after disconnecting the VGA monitor and just leaving the computer powered off for a day before booting with just the DVI monitor connected.

I'd love to know why this would work when immediate booting with just DVI after disconnecting the VGA didn't...

Comment: If your unsuccessful attempts started with the computer on and VGA attached, followed by disconnecting the VGA display and a soft restart (ex start menu-shutdown or reboot) instead of completely turning power off the card could have been caching information about what displays were connected instead of rescanning.  If you were turning the computer off before, but just for not as long, then I'm stumped too.

Answer (score 0):

gfx card got vga+dvi? or is it a dvi+dvi with one adapter? if so maybe move addapter to other dvi connector. If there actually are a real vga connector that is used as boot screen (seems odd) and there are no options in BIOS (would only be possible if gfx is integraded on motherboard I would think), I would say you are out of luck.